# how to add a class to symfony widget root element

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I was able to add a class to the form itself and for example to a `form_row` like you can see on the screenshot by adding a second parameter to form_start/form_row and so on.

But I was not able to find a solution to add a class to the parent of div.choice-box which already has the class form-group. What is the correct solution?

[image: symfony form output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was quite a simple solution - we have our own template file called `fields.html.twig` - I just opened the vendor file `bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig` and copied the necessary parts over into our template file were I was able to apply the needed changes.

Have a nice one.